# ExtJS 4 Add tooltips to overflowed cells in all project Ext.grid.Panel's

Tags: extjs, extjs4

**TL;DR:** What is the best way to add additional attribute (`data-qtip`) to cell inner DOM elements **in all project Ext.grid.Panel's at once**.

**Description:** I want to add tooltips to overflowed cells in all project Ext.grid.Panel's with full text.

I add simple extend to [`Ext.tip.QuickTip`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTip) (so I can keep all grid cell tooltip settings in one place) and call [`Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tip.QuickTipManager-method-init) with its `className` (later I want to extend / overrite `Ext.tip.QuickTipManager` to work with several `Ext.tip.QuickTip` child intances at same time):

```
Ext.define('Ext.lib.extensions.PortalGridCellTooltip', {
    extend: 'Ext.tip.QuickTip',
    alias: 'widget.portalGridCellTooltip',
    alternateClassName: 'Portal.PortalGridCellTooltip',

    tagConfig: {
        namespace: 'data-',
        attribute: 'gctip',
        width: 'gcwidth',
        target: 'target',
        title: 'gctitle',
        hide: 'hide',
        cls: 'gcclass',
        align: 'gcalign',
        anchor: 'anchor',
        showDelay: 'gcshowDelay'
    },

    onTargetOver: function (element) {
        var target = element.getTarget(this.delegate);

        if (!this.isOverflowed(target)) {
            return;
        }

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    /**
     * Check if passed element is overflowed with its content
     * @param element
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    isOverflowed: function (element) {
        var curOverflow = element.style.overflow;

        if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === "visible")
            element.style.overflow = "hidden";

        var isOverflowing = element.clientWidth < element.scrollWidth
            || element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight;

        element.style.overflow = curOverflow;

        return isOverflowing;
    }
});
```

I can add this tooltip with column renderer:

```
renderer: function (value, meta) {
    meta.tdAttr = 'data-gctip="' + value + '"';
    return value;
}
```

But how I can add tooltips to all project Ext.grid.Panel's at once? Solution must work with existing renders of columns, of course. I would be very grateful for professional advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this `ToolTip`, this works for any `Ext.grid.Panel`:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            target: Ext.getBody(),

            delegate: '.x-grid-cell',

            trackMouse: true,

            defaultAlign: 'l-l',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            listeners: {
                beforeshow: function(tip) {
                    var textEl = Ext.get(tip.triggerElement).down('.x-grid-cell-inner'),
                        text = textEl && textEl.dom && Ext.String.trim(textEl.dom.textContent || textEl.dom.innerText || ''),
                        triggerColumn = Ext.get(tip.triggerElement),
                        columnWidth = triggerColumn && triggerColumn.getSize().width,
                        textWidth = textEl && textEl.getSize().width,
                        grid = Ext.get(tip.triggerElement).up('.x-grid'),
                        view = grid && grid.dom && Ext.getCmp(grid.dom.id).getView(),
                        header = view && view.getHeaderByCell(tip.triggerElement),
                        renderer = header && !header.isXType('templatecolumn') && header.renderer,
                        record = view && view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement.parentNode),
                        encodedText = view && !view.isXType('tableview') && !view.isXType('treeview') && renderer ? renderer.call(header, text, {}, record, null, null, grid.getStore()) : text;

                    if (!encodedText || !text || !textEl || !textWidth || (columnWidth > Ext.util.TextMetrics.measure(textEl, encodedText).width)) {
                        return false;
                    }


                    tip.update(encodedText);
                }
            }
        });
```

A working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dlj

---

For adding a data attribute to the `td` you can override `Ext.grid.column.Column`:

```
initComponent: function() {
    var renderer;

    this.callParent(arguments);

    renderer = this.renderer || function(value) {
        return value;
    };

    this.renderer = function(value, meta) {
        meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';

        return renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dn5

Comment: Interesting solution! Thx, Ill give it a try.

Comment: I have a bug here, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/ToolTip.html#Ext-tip-ToolTip-method-onMouseMove `me.el.parent()` is null.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Can not reproduce in the fiddle, I'll try to investigate this issue deeper in my project. Actually I asked about your guess what can be the reason. Anyway, nice solution.

Comment: But if we talk about my question, can you, please, suggest override for grid (view?) so I can add `data-qtip` to cell in all project grids. Or its too bad approach?

Comment: General tooltip solution is very nice & dynamic (works on column resize too). The only adjustments I did, I have used textWidth in comparison instead of columnWidth, and passed ```true``` parameter on ```getSize()``` in order to exclude the 20px side padding